# Where is a comprehensive reference for the Spark SQL Windowing / analytic functions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The Spark version 1.5+ has windowing functions. I believe there were a comprehensive documentation for SQL *somewhere* but have been unsuccessful to find it .

Here is the docs for spark dataframe and sql: it does NOT have the content sought:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations

I have googled a number of different ways and unable to find the comprehensive guide to available sql functions.  The closest I could find is "spark 1.5 new Dataframe operations" here:

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights-datetimestring-handling-time-intervals-and-udafs.html

**Update**  I am looking specifically for a SQL reference - not an API (/scaladoc) reference. I.e. a reference showing the provided sql functions, what their arguments are, semantics, and maybe example usage.

Comment: More or less any source about window functions will be good.  Spark SQL more or less follows SQL standard although not options are implemented.

Comment: @zero323  Then we would be left to trial and error. If you have a reference to "spark supported windowing features" that would be on target.

Comment: Since at this moment window  functions support is based on Hive you can safely use [Hive docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-WindowingandAnalyticsFunctions). Regarding trail and error - I cannot agree. API is pretty much self documenting and reflects SQL 2003 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? This is spark2.4.0
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#last_value

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is a page about [Windowing and analytics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) in the Wiki which covers the window specification, aggregate functions, and it contains some examples.

Comment: That's the Hive manual.  Is there a spark page?  My concern is that we do not know what portions of the hive windowing are supported by spark - and what the differences are betwixt  them.  But in any case that page is at least helpful.

Comment: If you're using a HiveContext rather than a SQLContext you should get pretty complete support

Answer (score 0):

Databricks had a good introduction to window functions at https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html but the definitive documentation should always be the API docs, scroll right to the bottom 
[Dataframe functions API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)

Comment: Thx, I updated the OP: I am not looking for an API reference but a SQL reference.